# Firefox pinch zoom without trackpad

Tags: firefox, touchpad, zoom

Is there a shortcut or a setting in about:config that allows me to use the pinch zoom feature with mouse and keyboard only? I dont' have a touch pad but like the pinch zoom much more than the classic "CSS zoom".
I know I could use something like the Windows Magnifyer, but those tools rasterize the image...

Comment: you mean, you don't like the "normal" zoom that you can do with `ctrl`+ mousewheel ?

Comment: What exactly are you looking to do?  Obviously, pinch zoom is a gesture, so you can't do that without a touchpad or touchscreen.  Are you perhaps simply looking to magnify the entire viewport?

Comment: Yes, `ctrl` + mousewheel is not really a zoom, it just changes the dpi. I want to magnify the entire viewport WITHIN THE BROWSER so the edges of all vector graphics stay sharp. 
The feature is already there, but I need a way to use it without buying an external touchpad. I thought there could be a setting in about:config that switches the function of `ctrl` + mousewheel.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Starting from Firefox 83, you can set the property `mousewheel.with_control.action` to `5` in the `about:config` page.

`ctrl` + `mousewheel` will then control the pinch zoom instead of the regular zoom.

If you need another key binding, you can use one of:

```
mousewheel.default.action
mousewheel.with_alt.action
mousewheel.with_control.action
mousewheel.with_meta.action
mousewheel.with_shift.action
mousewheel.with_win.action
```

The possible values from Firefox source code are:

```
0: Nothing happens
1: Scrolling contents
2: Go back or go forward, in your history
3: Zoom in or out (reflowing zoom).
4: Treat vertical wheel as horizontal scroll
5: Zoom in or out (pinch zoom).
```

Comment: Textbook example of a good answer!